# R scales function oob_squish will not squish limits from 0 to 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below I have some code to create a `geom_tile` plot with a continuous color scale.

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:2,y = 0:20)
df$value <- runif(63,min = -10,max = 10)

ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "#030303",
    mid = "#4f4f4f",
    high = "#7f7f7f"
  )
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

I want to squish the scale to between 0 and 1 which I tried with the following code.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "#030303",
    mid = "#4f4f4f",
    high = "#7f7f7f",
    limits = c(0,1),
    oob = scales::oob_squish
  )
```

The new plot looks like the following.

[image]

You can see the limit colors are not between light grey and black anymore. I tried running the plot for different datasets as well but the code does not do what I want.

Comment: What if you map rescaled values to your `fill` aesthetic? ie `fill = scales::rescale(value)`

Comment: No that doesn't seem to work. I just want to squish values less than 0 and greater than 1 to those boundaries and keep the color scheme the same. So black at bottom and grey at top of the scale.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you are looking for better. In `scale_fill_gradient2()` you can specify where the new midpoint should be with `midpoint = 0.5` if your limits are from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping of `high`, `mid` and `low` seems to occur before the squishing, so it would be better to use `scale_fill_gradientn` here:

```r
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = c("#030303", "#4f4f4f", "#7f7f7f"),
    limits = c(0, 1),
    oob = scales::oob_squish
  )
```

[image]